# Appending lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using append to add a new username and password to my list. It only adds it temporarily to the list though, how can I add it permanently.

My code is:

```
list_usernames = ["person123",]
list_passwords = ["password123",]

new_username = input ("Create a username")
new_password = input ("Create a password")

list_usernames.append(new_username)
list_passwords.append(new_password)

print(list_usernames)
print(list_passwords)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "permanently"? This should add it as permanently as anything, except that your script ends after the print statements.

Comment: When you say *"permanently"* do you mean so that next time you run the script it's still there? That would require either: 1. editing the script itself at runtime (probably not a great idea); or 2. saving the data externally in a file or database. Note that, either way, passwords shouldn't be stored in plaintext - research "salting and hashing".

Answer (score 0):

You can not store data in script permanently. You need to use .txt file or database.

```
new_username = input ("Create a username")
new_password = input ("Create a password")

with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write(new_username + ' ' + new_password + '\n')
```

This statements will write into the file all new usernames and passwords

Answer (score -1):

Considering you want to store some no of usernames and passwords. Instead of running your code every time you can modify your code like this

```
list_usernames = ["person123",]
list_passwords = ["password123",]
counter=int(input())

while counter:
    new_username = input ("Create a username")
    new_password = input ("Create a password")

    list_usernames.append(new_username)
    list_passwords.append(new_password)

    print(list_usernames)
    print(list_passwords)

    counter-=1

print("usernames:",list_usernames)
print("passwords:",list_passwords)
```

In other cases, if you want to run your program multiple no of times it is advised to store data into files

Comment: It's not clear how this is answering the OP's question about storing these data "permanently".

Comment: Edited now @brunns :)